# How to fix 'variable is always true' or '... false'?

Tags: java

I am creating a program that tolls a certain section of a highway. At certain times there are different toll rates. I started this code but while using Intellij IDEA is says that my variables (hours, and min) are always true. After that first 'else if' statement the rest of the 'else if' statements say that the whole condition is always false. I'm guessing I may have set up an infinite loop maybe? I am very stuck and need a little push to move forward. (the return just gives the price during those certain times.)

```
/**
 * The method takes hour, minute, and "am", "pm" components of the time stamp of the moment when car crosses the bridge and calculates the toll rate.
 * If any of the time stamp components are invalid, -1 is being returned as an error code.
 * @param hour hour component of the time stamp
 * @param min minute component of the time stamp
 * @param amPm either string "am" or "pm", component of the time stamp
 * @return the toll rate
 */
public static double toll520Bridge(int hour, int min, String amPm) {
    if ((hour < 0 || hour > 12) || (min < 0 || min > 59) || (!"am".equals(amPm) && !"pm".equals(amPm))) return -1;

    else if ((hour <= 12 && hour >= 4) && (min <= 59) && ("am".equals(amPm))) return 1.25;

    else if ((hour <= 7 && hour >= 5) && (min <= 59) && ("am".equals(amPm))) return 1.4;

    else if ((hour <= 10 && hour >= 8) && (min <= 59) && ("am".equals(amPm))) return 2.05;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a loop at all.

Comment: If `hour` is not between 4 and 12, it's obviously not between 5 and 7 or 8 and 10. I think you want to switch the order.

Comment: I think what IntelliJ is trying to tell you is that based on the arguments you're providing to the method when you call it somewhere else in your code, the condition is always true.

Comment: @shmosel are you talking about the opening and closing braces?

Comment: I highly recommend using `{` and `}` for all of your if and else blocks. It doesn't take much effort, but it makes it easier to read and understand.

Comment: You already returned from the method in the first line if `hour > 12`, so the check for `hour <= 12` in the next line is *always true*. [Comment by shmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55623485/how-to-fix-variables-that-are-always-true-or-false#comment97939821_55623485) explains why the last two lines are *always false*. --- Also, since first line returns when `min > 59` , the `min <= 59` is similarly redundant, as it is also *always true*.

Comment: @Matt makes sense. Yes the arguments are set

Comment: What is return value if `"pm".equals(amPm)`? Oh, that is undefined, so the code will fail to compile.

Comment: @Andreas the first if statement checks for invalid input (which is from an argument later on in the program). I don't see how it would affect the first 'else if'.

Comment: @MosesMinchuk After a statement like `if (hour > 12) return;` it is absolutely guaranteed that `hour <= 12` for the remainder of the method *(or until `hour` is changed, but that doesn't happen here)*. Which means that `hour <= 12` is ... wait for it ... **always true**. --- The compiler knows this, and is telling you that the check is redundant and should be removed, or that you wrote the wrong condition and you need to fix it. The compiler cannot of course know which of the two is the actual problem, but it's doing the best it can to alert you to the potential problem.

Comment: @Andreas thank you makes more sense now.

Comment: @Andreas Minor nitpick: it's the IDE complaining, not the compiler.

Comment: @shmosel Nitpick: It's the IDE's compiler that is complaining. Which part of the IDE do you think does that type of code analysis, if not the compiler? E.g. in Eclipse IDE, warnings like that are referred to as "Compiler Errors/Warnings".

Comment: @Andreas Eclipse has its own compiler. Intellij uses javac as far as I know. I think that makes this more of a static code analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's reformat your code for clarity:

```
if ((hour < 0 || hour > 12) || (min < 0 || min > 59) || (!"am".equals(amPm) && !"pm".equals(amPm))) {
    return -1;
}
else if ((hour <= 12 && hour >= 4) && (min <= 59) && ("am".equals(amPm)))  {
    return 1.25;
}
else if ((hour <= 7 && hour >= 5) && (min <= 59) && ("am".equals(amPm))) {
    return 1.4;
}
else if ((hour <= 10 && hour >= 8) && (min <= 59) && ("am".equals(amPm))) {
    return 2.05;
}
```

The first `if` statement checks for invalid input parameters. You can refactor that into a separate method that returns true or false to make things easier to read:

```
private boolean parametersAreInvalid(int hour, int min, String amPm) {
    return (hour < 0 || hour > 12 || min < 0 || min > 59 || (!"am".equals(amPm) && !"pm".equals(amPm)));
}
```

Also, if your `if` block ends with a return, you don't need to use `else`.

```
if (parametersAreInvalid(hour, min, amPm)) {
    return -1;
}

if ((hour <= 12 && hour >= 4) && (min <= 59) && "am".equals(amPm))  {
    return 1.25;
}

if ((hour <= 7 && hour >= 5) && (min <= 59) && "am".equals(amPm)) {
    return 1.4;
}

if ((hour <= 10 && hour >= 8) && (min <= 59) && "am".equals(amPm)) {
    return 2.05;
}
```

Now we know that the `min` variable must be valid, so we don't need to keep checking if it is <= 59, and likewise the `hour` variable must be <= 12:

```
if (parametersAreInvalid(hour, min, amPm)) {
    return -1;
}

if (hour >= 4 && "am".equals(amPm))  {
    return 1.25;
}

if ((hour <= 7 && hour >= 5) && "am".equals(amPm)) {
    return 1.4;
}

if ((hour <= 10 && hour >= 8) && "am".equals(amPm)) {
    return 2.05;
}
```

Now the real problem - your second `if` statement covers a range of hours that includes the ranges for the third and fourth `if` statements. They need to be reordered. A clue is also in the pricing - you probably want to charge the highest toll that applies.

```
if (parametersAreInvalid(hour, min, amPm)) {
    return -1;
}

if ((hour <= 10 && hour >= 8) && "am".equals(amPm)) {
    return 2.05;
}

if ((hour <= 7 && hour >= 5) && "am".equals(amPm)) {
    return 1.4;
}

if (hour >= 4 && "am".equals(amPm))  {
    return 1.25;
}
```

You can nest `if` statements to cover off common tests:

```
if (parametersAreInvalid(hour, min, amPm)) {
    return -1;
}

if ("am".equals(amPm)) {
    if (hour <= 10 && hour >= 8) {
        return 2.05;
    }

    if (hour <= 7 && hour >= 5) {
        return 1.4;
    }

    if (hour >= 4)  {
        return 1.25;
    }
}
```

And lastly, your method still needs to return a value if none of the `if` statements match - what value should that be? Is the toll free outside of the above hours? If so, the last line of the method should be:

```
return 0;
```